# Telerik for UWP RadDataGrid. Getting single cell value from row selection

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, uwp, telerik

I am trying to get the value of a single cell when selecting a row or multiple rows so i can run a query to fill another grid for edit. My DataGrid is bound from a  dataset returned by a sql query from wcf service. i have tried accessing    grid.selecteditems and have been through the documentation on the datagrid. Any help would be appreciated. if you need any more information just ask!

Reply

Comment: Any issues with using `grid.selecteditems`?

Comment: it just gives the count of selected items. i can go into the drop down and see all of my columns in "Class1" (my data model used), but im not sure how to access the specific columns value i need.

Comment: i have tried using the column name and the index of a for loop _italic_ **bold** `for each item in grid.selecteditems 


x =grid.selecteditems(item.ColumnName)` with no luck. it gives me an index out of range exception.

Answer (score 0):

> i can go into the drop down and see all of my columns in "Class1" (my data model used), but im not sure how to access the specific columns value i need.

If in this case, it seems like  the `SelectionUnit` property for the `RadDataGrid` is `Row` which is the default value. If you want to the unit to select is a cell within a grid row, and get the value, you need to set the `SelectionUnit` to `Cell` as follows:

```
<telerikGrid:RadDataGrid
   x:Name="grid"
   IncrementalLoadingMode="Explicit"
   ItemsSource="{Binding}"
   SelectionMode="Multiple"
   SelectionUnit="Cell"
   SelectionChanged="grid_SelectionChanged"  />
```

And to define a Cell when using a selection you can use the `DataGridCellInfo` class, that holds all the information about it. Code behind for getting the values using `DataGridCellInfo` class for example:

```
 private void grid_SelectionChanged(object sender, Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.DataGridSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     var cells = grid.SelectedItems;
     foreach (DataGridCellInfo cell in cells)
     {
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(cell.Value);
     } 
 }
```

More details please reference [this document](http://docs.telerik.com/windows-universal/controls/raddatagrid/features/selection).